# How do I initialise an 'Abstract Entity' CoreDataClass using SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, core-data, swifty-json, codable

I have an Abstract Entity called 'User' in my Core Data model. I would like to initialise an instance of this entity without saving it into the database. Therefore I have set it as Abstract Entity.

I would like this entity class to conform to JSONAble as I am using SwiftyJSON to simplify things.

For it to conform I must implement the init method `required convenience init?(dict: [String : Any])`.

This is what the method looks like:

```
required convenience public init?(dict: [String : Any]) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    guard let codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext,
        let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: managedObjectContext) else {
        fatalError("Failed to decode User")
    }

    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: nil)

    let json = JSON(dict)
    let userDictionary = json["user"]

    id = userDictionary["id"].int32Value
    phoneCode = userDictionary["countryCode"].stringValue
    mobileNumber = userDictionary["mobileNumber"].stringValue
    firstName = userDictionary["firstName"].stringValue
    lastName = userDictionary["lastName"].stringValue
    avatar = userDictionary["avatar"].stringValue
    userRole = userDictionary["userRole"].int32Value

    let dateString = userDictionary["dateAdded"].stringValue
    if let date = dateString.asDate() {
        dateCreated = date
    }
}
```

Upon running this, it fails to decode the user and hits the fatalCrash that I have in place.

I am still a bit unsure on how Abstract Entities are meant to be initialised without being stored into the database, maybe if I can figure out the correct way to setup the CoreDataClass for Abstract Entities, I can figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: The whole point about an abstract class is that you can't instantiate it, you can only instantiate its sub-classes. That's what makes it abstract.

Comment: I basically want an entity that can be initialised, but not stored into the database. Am I right in thinking that a Parent entity would better suit than an Abstract entity?

Comment: `fatalError` is called because one of the three `let` statements in your `guard` do not complete - which one is it? Have you thought about creating a local `NSManagedObjectContext`, inserting your `JSON(dict)` into that?

Comment: @andrewbuilder it was the `let entity` statement. I found another way to initialise the entity for this scenario and that seemed to work. Thanks anyway.